# check if something exists and is executable in C, using stat function

Tags: c

For example, I have directory a and b under my current working directory. I'm trying to locate file X, how can I modify the `stat()` command so that it checks both directory a and b instead of just current working directory? would `stat(a/file, &buf)` work? also, to check if it's executable, I know the code is `buf.S_IXUSR`, does `if (buf.S_IXUSR)` work?

thanks!

Comment: yes I have, and I couldn't figure out how to get it to browse different directories, that's why I asked :/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you consult the [`stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) man page.

Here's an example of how to use `stat`:

```
struct stat buf;

if (stat("a/file", &buf) != 0) {
    // handle failure
}

// Check the `st_mode` field to see if the `S_IXUSR` bit is set
if (buf.st_mode & S_IXUSR) {
    // Executable by user
}
```

However, for your use case, you might consider [`access(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) instead:

```
if (access("/path/to/file", X_OK) == 0) {
    // File exists and is executable by the calling process's
    // _real_ UID / GID.
}
```

Comment: ahh i see! i was browsing `man stat`, didn't know there's `man 2 stat`, thanks!

Comment: hi again! I got everything to work for current directory, but I'm still strugling to get it to work for sub directories such as dir a and b, `stat("a/file", &buf)` doesn't seem to work since it always says no such file, even if the file is there

Comment: Is `a` a subdirectory of the program's current working directory?

Comment: yes it is, I'm using `char d1[50]` `strcat(d1, "a/")` `strcat(d1, "file")` to generate the string `"a/file"` since file is from user input, however every time I try to read d1, it gives me `@#!a/file`, no idea where those symbols came from

Comment: Use `strcpy(d1, "a/")`.

Comment: If you want to use `strcat`, you need to start with a string. That means initialize `d1[0] = '\0'`.