# random unwanted symbols in char array in C

Tags: c

Im trying to make an array of strings by using `strcat()`, however it keeps giving me unwanted characters, for example: `char arr[50]` `strcat(arr, "test")` and when I `puts(arr)` or `printf("%s\n", arr)`, it always gives me `@!*test` instead of just `test`, does anyone know what's causing my problem?

thanks!

Comment: OP is not following advice of [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689162/check-if-something-exists-and-is-executable-in-c-using-stat-function#comment59059092_35689199).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the array before using its value, or you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char arr[50] = {0}; /* add = {0} */
    strcat(arr, "test");
    puts(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a character array, you can use `char arr[50] = "";`, of course.